# Is this usage of 'zu' correct?

Tags: translation, word-usage, infinitive, gerund

> Eine andere Sprache zu sprechen, ist eine beeindruckende Fähigkeit zu haben.

I want to say:

> Speaking another language is an impressive skill to have.

I’m not sure if *speaking another language* translates to *eine andere Sprache zu sprechen*.

Comment: Yes, that part is fine.

Comment: The main problem with the sentence is the use of the generic verb *sein (ist)*. German speakers tend to avoid *sein* (when used as a full verb) and replace it by more specific verbs, e.g. spatial metaphors such as *stehen* or *liegen*. In this particular case, it's even wrong because in German you can't 'be' a *zu* construction. Either replace *sein* by *bedeutet* (still clumsy) or just drop "zu haben".

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a little too literally translated from English and a little clunky.
I would rather say in German:

> Es ist eine beeindruckende Fähigkeit eine andere Sprache zu sprechen.

The literal translation of *to have* sounds very not German.

Comment: "This sounds a little too literally translated from English and a little clunky". I think, you can be direct and say that it is wrong!

Comment: but nevertheless "zu" is used correctly

Comment: @Iris I don't think it's grammatically wrong, but it's a sentence that I've never heard put this way in German, it just sounds wrong.

Comment: @Sam, it is wrong! (see the comment of Hans Adler)

Answer (score 0):

*speaking another language* would directly translate to *das Sprechen einer anderen Sprache*, but *eine andere Sprache zu sprechen* (*to speak another language*) sounds much better in nearly every case.

Sam's answer is quite correct about the rather literal translation of *to have*, but:

> Es ist eine beeindruckende Fähigkeit, eine andere Sprache zu sprechen.

mind the comma.

Comment: A comment to my answer and editing my answer to add the comma would be the "stackexachangy" way to improve an almost identical answer...